# Electrical torque and electrical power of a generator?

Tags: power, generator, torque, speed

Having the electrical torque and the angular speed of a synchronous generator, can I calculate its electrical power output as the product between the electrical torque and its angular speed w (Pe=Te*w) as we do for the mechanical power (Pm=Tm*w)?

Comment: There is no electrical torque. All torque is mechanical. It doesn't matter how it is produced.

Comment: @DKNguyen if you check in simulation programs (like Etap, Digsilent, Nepam) you have the electrical torque...

Comment: They might call it that but it's still a mechanical property. It doesn't change anything about what torque is.

Comment: @DKNguyen yes but the question is not if the electrical torque physically speaking exists or not. I am telling you that in the electrical engineering literature the concept of electric torque exists. The question is if having the electric torque in output from of a generator inside the simulation tool I can calculate the electric power as Pe=Te*w. I know the electric power can be calculated in many way, but I want to understand if that specific way I am telling to you is valid or not

Comment: Read between the lines a bit. If I'm saying that all torque is ultimately mechanical, then that means that once you have a torque number, it is all the same. It doesn't matter where it came from.

Comment: @DKNguyen then why is it called electrical torque and not just torque?

Comment: It seems to be calculated from the electrical characteristics of the motor rather than a measurement at the shaft which would be subject to things like friction and other losses before getting to the shaft (and you can't use mechanical values to calculate the torque a motor is producing since it's an electromagnetic device). Kind of like the theoretical torque the motor is producing.

Comment: @DKNguyen Maybe they mean Back EMF?

Comment: @VoltageSpike I doubt OP would make that mistake because they know the mechanical relationship between torque and power

Comment: The torque at the airgap is different than the shaft torque, because the shaft torque is subject to other losses (air resistance and bearing friction). I am not familiar with electrical torque. But maybe it is the torque at the airgap. Anyway, I agree with @DKNguyen

Answer (score 2):

'Electrical Torque' is a thing like 'Mechanical Current'. You can write it down, and with a suitable definition it could perhaps mean something.

With a generator, or any electrical machine for that matter, the difference between input and output power goes as losses. There are two principal sources of loss, one mechanical, and one electrical.

The mechanical one is the torque due to friction and gas viscosity. This makes a difference between the mechanical torque at the shaft, and the torque in the armature due to the  Lorentz forces between the current flowing and the stator field. I would be happy to call this latter torque 'electrical torque', but I'd need to see it so defined before I could do so confidently.

The electrical loss is mainly IR voltage drop due to the armature resistance. This makes a difference between the terminal voltage, and the voltage generated in the armature due to its motion through the stator field. This latter voltage could also be termed 'electrical speed'.

I've worded those two paragraphs carefully to emphasise the symmetry between the losses on each side.

You can now define several different numbers for the power of the motor, by choosing which torque and which speed you multiply together, as they include different losses.

The shaft mechanical power is shaft speed * mechanical torque.

If you compute a power as shaft speed * 'electrical torque' (as I've defined it above), then you end up with a power that's neither the electrical terminal power, nor the shaft mechanical power. Is that useful to anyone?

Comment: My quick and dirty over-simplification for students who need a connection between the electrical and mechanical world is challanging here because your run-of-the-mill brushed DC motor it's voltage = rotational speed and current = torque. But in terms of comparing losses in a mechanical system, let's say a 1:1 pulley, your input and output rotational speeds are the same but you have lost torque. In an electrical system, say 1:1 transformer (ignoring magnetization current), you loose voltage instead of current so here your analogy would be opposite.